# How to find out which leads are converted from a specific landing page

Tags: marketing-definitions

From a Sitecore launchpad, is there a way I can identify which are the leads/contacts converted from a specific landing page ?

Thank you,

Roman

Comment: Can you please explain in details, As Sitecore has the tracking data, are you using sitecore forms or WFFM for lead generation?

Comment: We are looking to develop multiple landing pages for different courses to be used for paid search campaigns but not sure to use single or multiple sitecore forms (to capture name and email) for these landing pages to capture leads. Thus, a single form may be sufficient if sitecore's launchpad could provide a way to identify leads by their converted pages for our marketing team.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different campaign on each landing page - and you can then split the conversion by campaign. If some campaigns are group, campaign facets might be the right element

Comment: I concur. Separate/differentiated landing pages already indicate different funding (e.g. campaign) efforts going on.